# When converting decimal date to julian with %j strptime, how do you specify the year?

Tags: r, date, strptime

This code causes the julian year to default to the current year, but how can I specifiy that the year should be 2011?

```
fractionalDayofYear <-seq(300,302,0.1)
julianDate<-  format(strptime((fractionalDayofYear), format='%j'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Do you want the parts of days to be represented in the output too?

Comment: No, I'm just extracting the dates (no times), though maybe worth addressing that in answers since other folks might want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `as.difftime` to add the days + fractional days more accurately:

```
as.POSIXct("2010-12-31", tz="UTC") + as.difftime(fractionalDayofYear, units="days")
#[1] "2011-10-27 00:00:00 UTC" "2011-10-27 02:24:00 UTC" "2011-10-27 04:48:00 UTC" ...
```

If you don't care about the part days, then just paste a "2011" in there:

```
as.Date(paste("2011",fractionalDayofYear), format="%Y %j")
# [1] "2011-10-27" "2011-10-27" "2011-10-27" "2011-10-27" "2011-10-27" ...
```

Comment: Great, pasting the year works well for my application!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you are using and how you intend to use it.

Both `Date` and `POSIXt` objects are relative to "1970-01-01 00:00:00 -00:00". The `Date` "integer" value is a day, whereas the `POSIXt` "integer" value is one second.

If you are using `Date`s, then to make this somewhat convert-able, then you should add the "int" of the preceding Dec 31 (since Jan 1 is julian day 1). For today, that would be

```
as.Date("2017-12-31")
# [1] "2017-12-31"
as.numeric(as.Date("2017-12-31"))
# [1] 17531
```

so `17531 + fractionalDayofYear`.

If you are using `POSIXt`, then you'll need to do two things: find the numeric component for time, and convert your "integer-means-day" to seconds:

```
as.POSIXct("2017-12-31")
# [1] "2017-12-31 PST"
as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2017-12-31"))
# [1] 1514707200
(3600*24*fractionalDayofYear) + 1514707200
```

Note that this may not properly handle daylight-savings ...